# Getting the footer on the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This dreaded problem.

What I currently have

html:

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <div class="wrapper"></div>
 <div class ="footer"></div>
 </body>
 </html
```

css:

```
 * {
margin: 0;
 }
 html, body {
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
 }
 .wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
 }
 .footer
height: 36px; 
 }
```

The problem is when i inspect the rendered page with chrome a few problems I see:
1. The html tag has a height associated with it hmmm and its not the entire page height
[image: Not full height pic]
2. so I have div inside of the wrapper div that extends past the wrapper, body, and html tag?

My best guess is that if i can get the html to the page height I could style the footer to page bottom.

I was considering using javascript to grab the true height in pixels and passing that to height and ditching the percent. Only problem is I still want to know whats going on!

Thanks,
JT

Comment: Does the wrapper div contain floated elements?

Comment: I do believe a few are! Ok so i changed it to only things that are being floated are buttons and images ... but i dont see how this would provoke the html tag being all wacked up

Comment: Ok well.. foreach element containing floated elements.. Put a div before the elements(containing the floated) closing tag, with the css class specified in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just made the html body tags set via pixels and not percent. Nothing I tried above satisfied me.

Answer (score 2):

add this css to your wrapper divs

```
  wrapper_div{ overflow:hidden; }
```

this is a hack to recalculate floated elements inside an element. Otherwise the browser will forget about the floated elements, `overflow-hidden` does the trick or you can append a clear floated element to the bottom of the wrapper div like so

CSS

```
clear_float{
     clear:both; display:block;
     overflow:hidden; visibility:hidden;
     width:0px; height:0px;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="wrapperdiv">
    /* other HTML elements*/
    <div class="clear_float"></div>
  </div>
```

this is assuming that the troublesome div is classed `wrapperdiv`

**on second look this is completely invalid**

```
html, body {
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
}
```

you are setting the height twice in one declaration. `height: auto !Important` will take precedent over `height: 100%` so you need to decide whether you want your height automatically rendered over explicitly at 100%.

and your missing the opening block in this css declaration

```
.footer
 height: 36px; 
}
```

Comment: I think you got it! give me a second

Comment: On html and body element are now the entire page. the wrapper in the whole page. Problem...The sroll bar is now gone and i cant see the entire page and the footer is sticking to the bottom of the visible page instead of the bottom of the content.

Comment: try the second solution, append a clear floated div element to the div or body which ever one is the troublesome element.  like i said theres two ways to solve this problem, it all depends what makes the most since for you

Comment: the html and body tag are now the height of the visable page not bottom of content

Comment: at this point i'm confused at what's your problem. you could wrap all html elements thats inside of the `<body>` tag inside a wrapper div. when you do that you can add overflow-hidden to this wrapper div's style or append a clear_floated div element to the wrapper div. if i understand the problem correctly this should be the solution.

Comment: are you suggesting putting the footer inside the wrapper?

Comment: @tman yes append it. and that **should get the footer to the bottom of the page** but see my edit. you have some css syntax errors and drop the `height: 100%` attribute wheres theres `height: auto !important`

Answer (score 0):

Just before the closing tag of the wrapper add a div with the class 'clear'

CSS:

.clear { clear: both; }

.footer { margin-top: -36px;  }

The problem is that floated elements behave like absolute positioned elements.. They are not taken in account when calculating the height of the wrapper div.

Comment: So i added a <div class="clear"> just before the closing wrapper div and styled it...nothing...Why would the HTML and body tag not be to the bottom of the enterior div.

Comment: The problem is that floated elements behave like absolute positioned elements.. They are not taken in account when calculating the height of the wrapper div. I know.. sicky footers are horrible..

Comment: ok so I have it kind of working if i zoom out its perfect but when zoomed in there are no scroll bars to see the rest of the content.?

Answer (score -1):

If you want a facebook like fixed footer status bar. Try using the following css:

```
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
```